# Cannot get ComboBox selected item value

Tags: lazarus

I am using this code at the moment. I need to get the String value of the selected item of a ComboBox:

```
procedure TForm5.BitBtn5Click(Sender: TObject);
var c,k,t,g: string;
begin

 //Get the name of the items
 c := ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex];
 k := ComboBox2.Items[ComboBox2.ItemIndex];
 t := ComboBox3.Items[ComboBox3.ItemIndex];
 g := ComboBox4.Items[ComboBox4.ItemIndex];

 //Show it
 ShowMessage(c);

 end;
```

The ComboBoxes have items inside as you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/jTeWX8Us) because I fill them in an `onCreate` event of the Form5. When I press the BitBtn5 I have an error like this:

[image]

I have googled my problem and I have found the code is the same, but I have that error. Do you have any idea? (I am using lazarus 1.2.4)

Comment: It's *safer* (if that is your aim) to get those values simply by `ComboBox.Text`.

Comment: @TLama I didn't think about it, it's so simply... It works, thank you. But I still don't know why my code is wrong

Comment: Remove 'delphi' tag, because it's misleading. Lazarus raises an exception when item index is -1, Delphi does not.

Comment: Probably, some (or all) `ComboBoxN.ItemIndex` returns -1 (item not selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of your ComboBox's item index is -1. Set them to a valid index at form creatiton, eg:

```
ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
```

Comment: So is this an "exception" because I am using Lazarus? (It works now)

Comment: @Alberto - Well, I wouldn't put it that way. This is an exception because item index is not valid is more like it I guess. :)

Comment: @Alberto - You are welcome. To be frank I only checked the Win32 widget set. I don't actually know if other widget sets are doing the same check and raising the exception. For Win32, exception is raised in 'TWin32ListStringList.Get' function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Lazarus 1.4.2. The problem is that property **ItemIndex** is not updating when selecting items from ComboBox.
To force this index to get updated I just placed some dummy code (that is accessing the ItemIndex) in **OnChange** event of ComboBox (see below). Then I can read ItemIndex from other places, and the value is correct.

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := ComboBox.ItemIndex;
end;
```

I just encountered this problem now and I didn't find a proper solution on the internet. My post is very late but I hope this will help others.