# Cannot get combobox selected item value on click of another button

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, combobox

I have a combobox **cmbOptions** and a button **btnShowItem**

and here's the code:

```
private void btnShowItem_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string item = ((ComboBoxItem)cmbOptions.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(); //Exception is here
}
```

Below is the exception:

> **System.InvalidCastException**: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'."

I've already gone through a number of links like these:

[Cannot get ComboBox selected item value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675488/cannot-get-combobox-selected-item-value)

[ComboBox- SelectionChanged event has old value, not new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961118/combobox-selectionchanged-event-has-old-value-not-new-value)

[Get selected value from combo box in c# wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351603/get-selected-value-from-combo-box-in-c-sharp-wpf)

etc, etc..

But didn't get the solution.

Please note I need to get the value of comboboxItem on buttonclick only NOT on cmbSelectionChange event

Comment: Are you using Bindings or did you add a couple of `ComboBoxItem`s manually?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `.Content.ToString()` the entire thing is converted to string, and you are trying to cast this resultant string to `ComboBoxItem` such conversion is not permitted, But you can cast the `SelectedItem` to a `ComboBoxItem` and then take values from them. try something like this:

```
ComboBoxItem currentItem = (ComboBoxItem)cmbOptions.SelectedItem; // this will be the comboBoxItem
string item =currentItem.Content.ToString(); // gives you the required string
```

If you combine both the steps you can write like this:

```
string item =((ComboBoxItem)cmbOptions.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

**Additional note:**

Still, you are getting the same exception means `SelectedItem` will be a string, try to get the value like this: `string item = cmbOptions.SelectedItem.ToString()`, This will happen because you may assign the `DisplayMemberPath`

Comment: @Tushar: Could you please take a look into the updates

Comment: As i already said brother, same above exception is occurring and the code that I had writtern in problem and the code that you has answered both are same

Comment: try this `string item = cmbOptions.SelectedItem.ToString()` and also take a look into the additional notes in my post

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int x = 0; x < cboType.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            cboType.SelectedIndex = x;
            var typeCombo = ((ComboBox)cboType);
            var valueType = ((ComboBoxItem)typeCombo.SelectedValue);

            if (thisProductInfo.Type == valueType.Content.ToString())
            {
                cboType.SelectedIndex = x;
                break;
            }
        }

        //for (int x = 0; x < cboColor.Items.Count; x++)
        //{
        //    cboColor.SelectedIndex = x;
        //    var colorCombo = ((ComboBox)cboColor);
        //    var valueColor = ((ComboBoxItem)colorCombo.SelectedValue);

        //    if (thisProductInfo.Type == valueColor.Content.ToString())
        //    {
        //        cboColor.SelectedIndex = x;
        //        break;
        //    }
        //}
```

how about this one? the former works but the commented loop gives me an error of casting, tried selectedindex but same results, only the former works.

Comment: You should remove the not working (commented) block. Maybe you could explain the difference between 'SelectedValue' and 'SelectedItem'?

Comment: nah, im here to find answers, I dont know why the codes below wont work while the codes above does but they're basically the same.. very weird...